# LiveData. Cannot assign to ‘value’: the setter is protected/*protected and package*/ for synthetic extension

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I'm trying to implement a DB Observer with LiveData as described in the [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata).

As long as I'm programming in Kotlin I'm adapting the functions (originally written in Java) to it.

When trying to save the data I find this problem.

```
Cannot assign to ‘value’: the setter is protected/*protected and package*/ for synthetic extension in ‘<library Grade: android.arch.livecycle:livedata-core-1.1.1>’
```

Did anyone have this problem already?

This is my code:

> ViewModel:

```
class ProfileViewModel: ViewModel() {

    object FirstName: MutableLiveData<String>()

    fun getCurrentName(): LiveData<String> {
        return FirstName
    }
}
```

> Fragment

```
class ProfileFragment{

    private lateinit var model: ProfileViewModel

    // this is called onViewCreated. inputFirstName is an Edittext.
    override fun setUp() {
        model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ProfileViewModel::class.java)

        val nameObserver = Observer<String> { firstName ->
            inputFirstName.text = SpannableStringBuilder(firstName)
        }

        model.getCurrentName().observe(this, nameObserver)
    }

    fun saveProfileData() {
        val firstName = inputFirstName.text.toString()
        model.getCurrentName().value = firstName
    }
}
```

Comment: replace `fun getCurrentName(): LiveData<String>` with `fun getCurrentName(): MutableLiveData<String>`

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Would you elaborate it a bit more on an answer so we can keep it for the community?

Comment: see the difference in `LiveData#setValue()` and `MutableLiveData#setValue()` methods

Answer (score 69, accepted):

As @spkink suggested:

replace

```
fun getCurrentName(): LiveData<String>
```

with

```
fun getCurrentName(): MutableLiveData<String>
```

The error is caused because `setValue(T value)` is `protected` in LiveData (so you cannot call it) while it is `public` in `MutableLiveData`.

Answer (score 1):

```
model.getCurrentName().value = firstName
```

Please consider that handling the name value update inside the ViewModel might be a clearer solution, since you avoid having mutable public properties. Furthermore, here it could lead to even worse effects because you have two mutable public live data properties. For example:

> ViewModel

```
// keep your MutableLiveData private, so it's easier to find where mutations might happen in your code
// I changed a little how the variable is declared, as the way below seems to more common nowadays
private var _firstName = MutableLiveData<String>()

// LiveData should remain public, being a read-only interface with other classes like your fragment
fun getCurrentName(): LiveData<String> {
    return _firstName
}

/*
An alternative 
val firstName = LiveData<String>
    get() = _firstName
*/

fun setFirstName(firstName: String){
    _firstName.value = firstName
}
```

> Fragment

```
fun saveProfileData() {
    val firstName = inputFirstName.text.toString()
    // the value update will be handled inside the ViewModel, where the private mutable live data property is located
    model.setFirstName(firstName)
}
```